# How to select text and keep a background color within its selection?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, mask, selections

This may be a confusing title as I am not quite sure what the proper terminology is.

I have a font that is grungy/broken and not completely solid. I added a background layer of black, and I want to keep that black color behind that font, but only behind the font, not on the whole canvas.

Here is an example of my setup with the font and a solid background.
[image]

As you can see when I select the text layer, it is picking up all of the broken sections on the font and it is not a solid shape.

[image]

My goal here is to keep the black behind the font itself, where you can see it in the broken parts of the text, but not have the rest of the background black. In the image below, the two red lines point to areas within the text where explaining of what I want to keep.

The end goal here is if I turn off layer 1 (the black background), I want to be able to see the black behind these letters and not have them be transparent.

What approach can I take to accomplish this?

[image]

I did this manually by tracing the letter with a lasso and selecting the inverse to delete everything except for my selection as an example of what I am trying to end up with. Hoping there is an easier way to do this but wanted to show my end goal.
[image]

Comment: So the font itself has that distressing at the bottom of its glyphs? The distressing isn't something you've added?

Comment: That is correct, the font for this example is here - https://www.fontspace.com/kc-fonts/scorched-earth?text=ABCD

Comment: Then I think your current method or defining the glyph shape is about the only way. Unless you can find a base font without the distressing.

Comment: The font also has transparent portions in the letters. If you create an indesign doc and add a layer of any color you want and a text layer with the 'ABCD' in that font. Then, you select the text and add a fill and stroke colors (i.e., white & black respectively). You'll see that the font has jagged edges and transparent sections. I agree with @Scott. I would use another (solid) font and create a clipping mask with a distressed image.